# Clear ajax response after server process completion

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an AJAX code which takes input from the radio form. 
When the server code satisfies a certain type of if() condition, it gets redirected to other page of my site for example, **dashboard.php** !

When it redirects, I still see the radio button form on the **dashboard.php** ! (which is not coded on that page...)

http://oi60.tinypic.com/30u7haq.jpg

For redirecting, I have used php function :

```
header('location:dashboard.php');
```

I need to somehow clear the response or disable the response when the code is redirected to the dashboard.php

AJAX Code:

```
function sendid(attack)
{
var att;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("r1").checked = false
     document.getElementById("r2").checked = false

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","battleuser2.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("att="+attack);

}
```

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you'll need to do your redirect after the ajax completes, not in the code that handles the ajax request...

try...

```
window.location.href = 'dashboard.php';
```

in your ajax success handler...

and remove the...

```
header('location:dashboard.php');
```

in your ajax handler

UPDATE:

Ajax handler (battleuser2.php)

```
if(true){
  echo 'success';
}else{
  echo 'fail';
}
exit;
```

Ajax complete:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  if(xmlhttp.resonseText == 'success'){
    window.location = 'dashboard.php?msg=You Won!';
  }else{
    window.location = 'dashboard.php?msg=You Lost!';
  }
}
```

Dashboard.php..

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
  echo $_GET['msg'];
```

Comment: I haven't used jquery! :\ only javascript and ajax

Comment: ajax is asyncronous meaning it will stay on the page it executes from.. the php handler will do the redirect but only on the server, the client won't see it, that's why the form remains...

native javascript ajax implementation also provides a way to do things when the request is complete

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    window.location.href = 'dashboard.php';
    }
  }

Comment: Ohkk! But what about my if() condition? the if condition determines the end of the server processing! where should I place it?

Comment: well you could return a response and exit..
if(true){
  echo 'success';
  exit;
}else{
  echo 'fail';
  exit;
}

then in your ajax complete code you can test... xmlhttp.responseText == 'success' or 'fail' and act accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax function is not loading a whole new page into the browser and thus the browser is not automatically processing the headers in the ajax response for a redirect.  So, from your Ajax call, the server can't automatically cause the browser to go to a new page.

If you want that to happen, you will need to stop using an ajax call and just use a regular form post (where the server returns the response page which will be processed for a redirect).

Or, you can do the redirect manually in your own javascript that processes the result of the ajax call.  Doing it yourself in your javascript code would look like this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  {
    window.location = 'dashboard.php';
}
```

Comment: But the page you see having "You Won" text in the pic, I provided! is indeed dashboard.php! means its actually redirected but haven't ended the ajax! the ajax code is still processing..

Comment: @user3636516 - NO, you've manually inserted that HTML into your page yourself to simulate that page - there was no redirect.  You have a page that is still the original page with part of it modified with the new content.  You will notice that the URL bar in the browser does not point at dashboard.php.  See latest edits to my answer.

Comment: If I don't use ajax, then how can I pass the results on the processes of server... to the client page? I mean PHP isn't having any response system! :\

Comment: to do it without ajax, just set the action in your form to the php handler..then your redirect in php will work as expected..you're mixing 2 different technics..

Comment: @user3636516 - it sounds like you just want a normal form post (see description of how it works [here](http://www.simfatic.com/forms/help/v40/how_does_an_html_form_work_.html)), not an ajax call.  Server-side redirects will be processed by the browser on the form post response.  jsuna is right here.  You're trying to do an ajax and wondering why it doesn't behave like a form post.